# Quantile-calculation example: Why the term $c$?

Tags: quantiles, exponential-distribution, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I need help to interpret a solution to the following example:

Based on historical claim amounts $x_1,...,x_{47}$, which are assumed to be outcomes from an unknown claim distribution, you are considering a qq-plot where the empirical quantiles of the logarithmic sample is compared to the corresponding quanile-values of the exponential distribution with parameter 1. The quantile-pairs approximately describes a straight line with intercept 0. We have that
$\frac{1}{47} \sum_{k=1}^{47} ln(x_k) \approx 0.4$. Estimate the 95%-quantile $F_X^{-1}(0.95)$ for the unknown claim distribution.

The given solution:

The relation $F_{log(X)}^{-1}(p)=-c \cdot ln(1-p)$ holds approximately for some $c$, i.e. approximately $P(log(X) \le x)=1-e^{-x/c}$, i.e. $log(X)$ is exponential with mean $c$. Here $c$ is estimated to $0.4$.
$P(X \le x)=P(log(X) \le log(x))=1-exp\{{-log(x)/c\}=1-x^{-1/c}}$, i.e. $X$ is Pareto-distrubuted. The quantile-function is $F_{X}^{-1}(p)=(1-p)^{-c}$, i.e. $F_X^{-1}(0.95) \approx 3.314454$.

Problem:

I don't understand where this $c$-term comes from, I thought the exponential distribution had the parameter 1, not $c$?

Comment: This *seems* to be an attempt to show that every "unknown" distribution is a Pareto distribution!